# Can't run 'Hello World" Spring MVC code

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I took the following example from Spring's website, trying to understand the basic concepts but so far I've only been struggling with configuration.

So here's web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Components to configure as beans -->
<!-- @Controller, @Service, @Configuration, etc. -->
<context:component-scan base-package="xyz.sample.baremvc" />

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

Then HomeController.java

```
package xyz.sample.baremvc;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String home() {
        System.out.println("HomeController: Passing through...");
        return "WEB-INF/views/home.jsp";
    }
}
```

And finally home.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello World!
    </body>
</html>
```

For completeness this is the folder structure

[image]

So I run this project and I get the following message:

```
Nov 29, 2013 11:14:33 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Springer2/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
```

I tried to play around with path names and whatnot but nothing seems to work. I can't fathom why I'm having so much trouble running such simple code after taking it directly from the horse's mouth.

Answer (score 2):

Since you placed all your classes inside the resources directory they won't get compiled. Move all packages to *src/main/java*.

Comment: @spacitron This is the correct answer. You need to make `/src/main/java` a source folder.

Comment: Do you still get the **org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound** message in your logs? Because this indicates your annotated controller is not found on the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

What URLs have you tried?
I think the URL pattern in the `web.xml` mapping should be `/*` instead of `/`.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/Springer2/ and http://localhost:8080/Springer2 and http://localhost:8080/ and I also played with the internal paths in the controller and package names in the dispatcher servlet. Also I just tried using /* and I have the same error